# mysql - function like isnull() to check for zero-value

Tags: mysql, substring, zero, isnull

I'm looking for a function to check if a column has the value 0 that behaves like the `isnull()` function.

This is what I've got so far:

```
CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING(textCol, 1, 
            LOCATE(DATE_FORMAT(dateCol,'%d.%m.%Y  %H:%i'), textCol)-1),
            '|',
             -1),       
    SUBSTRING(
        textCol,
        LOCATE(DATE_FORMAT(dateCol,'%d.%m.%Y  %H:%i'), textCol),
        IFNULL(
            LOCATE( /* this will return 0 if it's the last entry */
                '|', 
                textCol, 
                LOCATE(DATE_FORMAT(dateCol,'%d.%m.%Y  %H:%i'), textCol)
            ) - LOCATE(DATE_FORMAT(dateCol,'%d.%m.%Y  %H:%i'), textCol),
            LENGTH(textCol))))
```

The data in textCol is sort of like a CSV-file with another CSV-file inside each column. Each dataset is delimited by `|` while each dataset inside that is delimited by `&&`. The inner fields are name, date like `'%d.%m.%Y  %H:%i'` and a comment.

i want to extract the dataset that corresponds to a certain DATETIME I've got in `dateCol`. The problem is that if the one I'm looking for is the last entry in `textCol`, the `LOCATE` (see comment) returns 0. But that breaks my `SUBSTRING` so only the first half of the entry is returned.

I added a `ISNULL()`, which of course doesn't do anything here. What I would like to do is have something similar to the `ISNULL()` that sort of does a `ISZERO()`, much like the `||` operator in Perl behaves.

There might be an alltogether better way to achieve what I want. Please don't hesitate to tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  CASE expression WHEN 0 THEN 'a substitute for zero' ELSE expression END
FROM    mytable
```

Comment: Thank you. That would work. I already thought about ``SELECT IF(expression = 0, 'a substitute for zero', expression)`` which does the same. Both cases are rather looong in my case, though.

Answer (score 16):

Might be useful here: there is a funky way to check if expression is either NULL *or* 0:

```
IFNULL(NULLIF(expr, 0), alt_expr)
```

This returns *alt_expr* if *expr* is NULL or 0, otherwise returns *expr*.

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 10):

This is shorter and avoids repeating expression:

```
SELECT COALESCE( NULLIF( expression, 0 ), 'a substitute for zero' ) FROM mytable
```

Comment: NULLIF is a great idea